# How to visualize reusable xibs in storyboards using IB_DESIGNABLE?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode9.2

**I want to visualize XIB's in a storyboard using the IB_DESIGNABLE constant in Xcode 9.2 with Objective C targeting iOS SDK 11.2.**

According [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402908-prepareforinterfacebuilder) from Apple the `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` method is called by the Interface Builder to let you do whatever shall only be done for the Interface Builder.

> When Interface Builder instantiates a class with the IB_DESIGNABLE attribute, it calls this method to let the resulting object know that it was created at design time. You can implement this method in your designable classes and use it to configure their design-time appearance.

Based on this [article](https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-visualize-reusable-xibs-in-storyboards-using-ibdesignable-c0488c7f525d) I want to visualize XIB's in my storyboard. When I use a `UIView` element on a ViewController and set

- first the custom class to `XibView`
- second the `nibName` property to `MainViewController`, the name of the XIB file

I get the following buildtime error:

```
Main.storyboard:
error: IB Designables: 
Failed to render and update auto layout status for MainViewController (8zi-kg-fjR):
The agent threw an exception.
```

What am I doing wrong that I get this error instead the visualized XIB in the View I use in the Main.storyboard?

This is the `XibView.h`

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface XibView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView* contentView;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSString* nibName;
@end
```

This is the `XibView.m`

```
#import "XibView.h"

@implementation XibView

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *) coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder: coder];
    if (self)
    {
        [self xibSetup];
    }
    return self;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self xibSetup];
    }
    return self;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder
{
    [super prepareForInterfaceBuilder];
    [self xibSetup];
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

- (void)xibSetup
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:_nibName owner:nil options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.contentView];
    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
}

@end
```

Comment: First thing that jumps out.... you implement `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`, in which you ***CALL*** `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` ... infinite loop?

Comment: Removed it and updated the question. It was from a test I did.

Comment: how about use swift?

Comment: @E.Coms Thanks for the hint. How would that help me solving this issue?

Comment: I tried swift. It did not work either. Maybe you need other method to achieve your goal. Not this way anymore

Comment: Thanks for trying @E.Coms. I guess the article I linked should still work also for swift. I figured it out with Objective C. I've to clean up some code and will post an answer here.

Comment: I have figured it out too. Translating has some tricks and should be exactly same. Anyway, it's a good method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180953/discussion-between-bruno-bieri-and-e-coms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [@E.Coms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10335956/e-coms) and still based on [this article](https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-visualize-reusable-xibs-in-storyboards-using-ibdesignable-c0488c7f525d) I figured it out what the problem was. To deliver an answer to be used for others here you can find the steps

**How to visualize reusable xibs in storyboards using IB_DESIGNABLE with Objective-C?**

1. Create a Xib holder objective-c header and class file (`XibViewHolder`)
2. Create a Xib file (`MyView.xib`)
3. Set the Xib's 'File's Owner' class to `XibViewHolder`
4. On your storyboard on any view controller add a `UIView`
5. Set that `UIView`'s class to `XibViewHolder` class
6. Set that `UIView`'s Interface Builder property called Nib Name, which is defined in the Xib holder class, to the name of the Xib you want to load e.g.: `MyView`.

This is the `XibViewHolder.h`

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface XibViewHolder : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* contentView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable NSString* nibName;
@end
```

This is the `XibViewHolder.m`

```
#import "XibViewHolder.h"

@implementation XibViewHolder

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self xibSetup];
}

- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder
{
    [super prepareForInterfaceBuilder];
    [self xibSetup];
    [self.contentView prepareForInterfaceBuilder];
}

- (void)xibSetup
{
    if (_nibName == nil) { return; }
    UIView* loadedNibView = [self loadViewFromNib];
    loadedNibView.frame = self.bounds;
    loadedNibView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    [self addSubview:loadedNibView];
    self.contentView = loadedNibView;
}

- (UIView*)loadViewFromNib
{
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    UINib* nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:_nibName bundle:bundle];
    return [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil].firstObject;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the method that I think has a bug:

```
- (void)xibSetup
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:_nibName owner:nil options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.contentView];
    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

The nib loader can't set `self.contentView` because you didn't pass `self` as the `owner` argument to `loadNibNamed:options:`. Try this instead:

```
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:_nibName owner:self options:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I set `owner` to `self` but no effect. Still the same error.

Comment: Did you also connect the `contentView` outlet in the xib?

Comment: No, why would I do that? To my understanding the contentView holds the loaded xib.

Comment: Why do you think `contentView` holds the loaded xib if you don't connect the outlet in the xib?

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoints in your code and then using Editor > Debug Selected Views in your xib?